# How many nine digit numbers are divisible by $4$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many nine-digit integers consisting of each of the digits $1-9$ exactly once are divisible by $4$?

My idea to solve this problem:

Let $$n = a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{9}, \text{where}~ a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{9}~\text{are integers which lies between $1$ and $9$ (inclusive)}. $$ Here $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots + a_{9}=45$. Now, let us fix the unit digit, it has to be an even number, so $4$ choices. Now, we need to make $4$ cases. But for those cases how to choose numbers at tens and other higher places?

Comment: Only the last two digits matter for divisibility by $4$ (since $4$ divides $100$)

Comment: The divisibility rule for 4 states that if the last two digits of a number is divisible by 4, then the number, itself, is divisible by 4.  (i.e. 17,536 is divisible by 4 because 36 is divisible by 4.)

Comment: Ok, so if unit digit is $4$, then digits at tens place can be $2,6$ or $8$ and other choices will be $3 \times7!$. And similarly other cases. Am I correct?

Comment: And total choices will be $(5+3+5+3)7!$

Comment: From where are you getting (5 + 3 + 5 + 3)?

Comment: It would help to know the divisibility rule of four.  Do you know it?  A number is divisible by $4$ if the second to last digit is even and the last digit is $0,4$ or $8$ or if the second to last digit is odd and the last digit is $2$ or $6$.

Comment: To go into too much detail:   Your number is going to be in the form $100A + 10B +C$ where $A$ is s seven digit number and $B$ and $C$ are single digits.  And $100A + 10B + C = 4\times 25A + 8B + 2B+C$ so your number will be divisible by $4$ if and only if $2B + C$ is.  If $B=2k$ is even then $2B+C= 4k +C$ and your number will only be divisible by $4$ if $C$ is.  If $B = 2k+1$ then $2B+C = 4k + (C+2)$ and that will be divisible by $4$ if $C$ has a remainder of $2$ when divided by $4$.... This is a handy rule to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ denote the set of $9$-digit numbers with distinct digits.

**Claim 1:** *As noted above, an integer $k$  is divisible by $4$ iff $k \bmod {100}$ is divisible by $4$.*

The number of numbers $x$ in $C$ divisible by $4$, where the last digit of $x$ is a $4$ or $8$: Then by Claim 1 the last digit of $x$ is $4$ or $8$, and the next-to-last digit of $x$ has to be *even*, which leaves $3$ choices [there are $4$ even digits in $\{1,2,\ldots,9\}$ and one of those $4$ even digits was used for the last, so now there are $3$ digits left to use], as it cannot be the same as the last digit. Then this leaves $7!$ choices for the remaining $7$ digits of $x$. So the number of such $x$ is $2×3×7!$.

The number of numbers $y$ in $C$ divisible by $4$, where the next-to-last digit of $y$ is $2$ or $6$. Then by Claim 1, the next-to-last digit in $y$ must be *odd*, which leaves $5$ choices. Then this leaves $7!$ choices for the remaining $7$ digits of $y$. So the number of such $y$ is $2×5×7!$.

So the number of numbers in $C$ divisible by $4$ is $2×(3+5)×7!$. Can you see why this is.

Comment: Your solution does not account for the cases in which the ones digit is 0.  - Ignore this comment.  I misread the hypothesis.

Comment: @S.A.Lloyd by hypothesis stated the the OP all the digits are $1,2,3,\ldots, 9$.

Comment: @Mike How can we have four choices if last digit is $4$ or $8$? It should be $3$.

Comment: @Math__Nerd you are correct. There are only $4$ even digits in $\{1,2,\ldots,9\}$, not $5$ as I was thinking at the time. My mistake good catch!